# How do I remove the lines from my chapterstyle in the Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, chapters

I'm using `memoir`and `bianchi`. I want my ToC page to be a blank page with nothing but the ToC on. I'm halfway there, but the lines insert by `bianchi`persists:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[book]{memoir}
\chapterstyle{bianchi}

% Remove name from ToC
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand\contentsname{}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents* 

\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\chapter{Foo}

Here is Chapter 1.

\end{document}
```

How do I get rid of these two horizontal lines?

Comment: Just remove `\chapterstyle{bianchi}` from your preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `\chapterstyle{bianchi}` in your preamble which affects the TOC. You could remove this to get the desired result.

But I would use

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\chapterstyle{bianchi}

\renewcommand*\tocheadstart{\cleardoublepage}
\renewcommand*\printtoctitle[1]{}
\renewcommand*\tocmark{\markboth{}{}}% avoids a header entry on a possible second TOC page
\renewcommand*\aftertoctitle{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents* 
\chapter{Foo}
Here is Chapter 1.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]